# Block_reduce with torch tensors on GPU

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, scikit-image

I have a 2D tensor and I am trying to reduce it by taking average of every 4 columns. For numpy arrays this can be done by using the block_reduce function from skimage.measure module.

I can use it for CPU torch tensors too, as it converts the input tensor to numpy array in the background. This won't work when my tensors are loaded on the GPU. Is there some efficient way to achieve this in PyTorch?

Here is what I want to do, illustrated by block_reduce:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from skimage.measure import block_reduce

t1 = np.array([[0,4,2,4,1,1,1,5],[1,4,2,4,1,1,1,5],[2,4,2,4,1,1,1,5],[3,4,2,4,1,1,1,5]]).astype('float')
t1 = torch.from_numpy(t1)

t2 = block_reduce(t1, block_size=(1,4), func=np.mean)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

The output produced:

```
tensor([[0., 4., 2., 4., 1., 1., 1., 5.],
        [1., 4., 2., 4., 1., 1., 1., 5.],
        [2., 4., 2., 4., 1., 1., 1., 5.],
        [3., 4., 2., 4., 1., 1., 1., 5.]], dtype=torch.float64)
[[2.5  2.  ]
 [2.75 2.  ]
 [3.   2.  ]
 [3.25 2.  ]]
```

Comment: Are interpolation or average pooling possible options?

Comment: @hkchengrex Yes, torch.nn.functional.avg_pool1d turns out to be exactly what I needed!